# Angular - Scroll to top when autoscroll="true" not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When certain pages in my Angular app are loaded they are not at the top of the page.

I've tried using `autoscroll="true"` on the `ng-view` however this isn't working. I believe this is because above the `ng-view` I have a nav menu that has some 'complex' positioning.

So instead I'm trying to use `$window.scrollTo(0,0);` with `$routeChangeSuccess` however its not working at all.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$window', function($rootScope, $route, $window) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $window.scrollTo(0,0);
      //Some other stuff here relating to meta and title in head
    });
}])
```

Adding additional code - I guess its important to mention that the ngview is sitting within my own 'contentSection':

```
<contentSection id="theContentSection">
      <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>
</contentSection>
```

SOLUTION:

Fixed this using: `angular.element('#theContentSection')[0].scrollTop = 0;`

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if $window.scrollTo(0,0) is a recognized function, but you can try this : 
$window.pageYOffset = 0

Answer (score 0):

You just try this..

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }); 
})
```

Otherwise simply add this

```
<ui-view autoscroll="true" />

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Comment: Nope - I guess my question is whats wrong with `$window.scrollTo(0,0);` why wouldn't that just work?

Answer (score 0):

try with viewContentLoaded event.

As per the Docs

$viewContentLoaded - fired once the view is loaded, after the DOM is rendered

However you will still have to additionally give some timeout to make it work

```
     $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
         $timeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0,0)},1000);
     });
```